# How to create a json object in the following format, javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create the following object dynamically in javascript:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Dole"
    }
}
```

I am not sure the best way to do this without hard coding it like this:

```
var jsonObject = 

{
    "data": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Dole"
    }
};
```

What is the best way to do this in javascript, do I have to create an array and stringify it? thanks.

Comment: A "JavaScript object notation object".  i.e. a JavaScript object?   And simply instantiating an object is not what I would call "hard coding".  What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Why is it a problem declaring it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// initiate an empty object
var jsonObject = {};
// assign a value to a new property - that property value is an object
jsonObject['data'] = {};
// assign a value to a property - that property value is a string
jsonObject.data['name'] = 'Bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic values/keys to objects in javascript as follows:

Say you have an object: `var obj = {};`

And you have two variables, one that defines the key, and one that defines the value.

```
var myKey = "someKey", myVal = "someVal";
```

You can add it to the object as follows:

```
obj[myKey] = myVal;
```